# Server response time in browser

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, dom, rendering, server-response

After all searches in google I cant found answer. I have requested for some data from server. it takes some time to load in browser. I don't know whats happening. So I have pasted the browser network time.
I want to is, server response is slow or the browser rendering is slow.
please describe all the things in image, it will be helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server is slow 1.5 seconds wait from request sent to the very small answer being returned.

There is also an initial delay setting up the connection but that is ok is being reused.

However, your picture does not show any details of the browser delay.

I would focus on improving the server response.

Comment: Rerun the test in the browser without any breakpoints in your code an you should see the entire picture of html loading, js files loading, then calls to the server and if there is changes to display in the browser you will see a time to display the returned data. However, in your example the data returned looks tiny. So most of the rendering will have been done when html and images were displayed.

Answer (score 1):

The connection seems to be very slow here. TTFB here means "Time To First Byte", which I think is explicit enough : It's the time spent just waiting for the first data byte to arrive once the request is finished sending.

Given how long it takes to receive a response and how fast it is for the content to download (the last 0.5 ms), I think the server is at fault here. It takes way too much time to send a response to your request.